# Operator T with rank T=1

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $h,g$ in Hilbert space $H$. Define $T:H\rightarrow H$ by $Tf=\langle f,h\rangle g$. Would you help me to prove that $\dim(\operatorname{ran}(T))=1$.

Next, show that If $T$ is finite rank, then there is orthonormal vectors $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and vectors $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ such that $Th=\sum_{j=1}^n \langle h,e_j\rangle g_j$ for all $h$ in $H$.

Thanks.

Comment: Among other TeX improvements, I changed $<f,h>$ to $\langle f,h\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k\in\text{ran} T$. Then $k=Tf$ for some $f$, i.e. $k=\lambda g$, where $\lambda=\langle f,h\rangle$. So every element in $\text{ran}\,T$ is a scalar multiple of $g$. Thus, $\text{ran}\,T$ has a basis consisting of $\{g\}$, i.e. it has dimension $1$.

Now assume that $T$ is finite rank. Let $g_1',\ldots,g_n'$ be an orthonormal basis of $\text{ran}\,T$. Then, for every $f\in H$, $Tf=\sum_j\lambda_j(f)\,g_j'$, with the coefficients $\lambda_1(f),\ldots,\lambda_n(f)$ uniquely determined for for each $f$. So, for each $j$, the map $f\mapsto\lambda_j(f)$ is a linear functional on $H$. Note that
$$
|\lambda_j(g)|\leq\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k(f)|^2\right)^{1/2}=\|Tf\|\leq\|T\|\,\|f\|,
$$
so every $\lambda_j$ is a bounded functional. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exist vectors $e_1',\ldots,e_n'$ such that $\lambda_j(f)=\langle f,e_j'\rangle$. So
$$
Tf=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle f,e_j'\rangle\,g_j',\ \ \ \ \ f\in H.
$$

Now, using Gram-Schmidt, there exist $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, orthonormal, such that 
$$
e_k'=\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_{kj}e_j
$$
for coefficients $\{\lambda_{kj}\}_{k=1,\ldots,n; j=1,\ldots,k}$ (note that these are not the equalities from Gram-Schmidt, but rather the *inverse* form, where we express the old vectors in terms of the new orthonormal ones). Then 
$$
Tf=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle f,e_k'\rangle\,g_k'=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle f,\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_{kj}e_j\rangle\,g_k'=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_{kj}\langle f,e_j\rangle\,g_k'=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle f,e_j\rangle\,\left(\sum_{k=j}^n\lambda_{kj}g_k'\right).
$$
Letting $g_j=\sum_{k=j}^n\lambda_{kj}g_k'$, $j=1,\ldots,n$, we get the desired expression.

Comment: How about gram-schmidt process to {$e_1$,...,$e_n$}?

Comment: Let me think about it for a little while.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll include it in the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Done. ${\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \          }$

Comment: Can i ask one more question ? Why $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle e_i,g_i\rangle$ is independent of selection of $\{e_i\}$ and $\{g_i\}$

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your comment, but $e$ and $g$ have a relation, in the answer, $\lambda$ is selected by $g$, and $e$ is selected by $\lambda$, can we select value of $g$ or $e$ arbitrary?

Comment: You are absolutely right. You have, since the $e_j$ are orthonormal,$g_j=Te_j$; so $$\sum_{j=1}^n\langle g_j,e_j\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle Te_j,e_j\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(T).$$

Comment: Yes, $g_j=Te_j$, then the sum is its trace, I got it, Thank you so much!